# Is the name of the target database available as a variable when using schemachange?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, schemachange

I want to use [schemachange](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange) to deploy this script:

`GRANT ALL ON DATABASE {{SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE}} TO ROLE {{database_power_user_role}};`

The value for `{{SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE}}` needs to be the name of the database that is being deployed to. In other words, the value passed to the `--snowflake-database` option of schemachange

```bash
> schemachange --help
usage: schemachange deploy [-h] [--config-folder CONFIG_FOLDER] [-f ROOT_FOLDER] [-m MODULES_FOLDER] [-a SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT] [-u SNOWFLAKE_USER] [-r SNOWFLAKE_ROLE] [-w SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE] [-d SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE]
                           [-c CHANGE_HISTORY_TABLE] [--vars VARS] [--create-change-history-table] [-ac] [-v] [--dry-run] [--query-tag QUERY_TAG] [--oauth-config OAUTH_CONFIG]

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
...
...
  -d SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE, --snowflake-database SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE
                        The name of the default database to use. Can be overridden in the change scripts.
```

Is that value available as a builtin environment variable? I've searched the documentation and can't find any reference to such a thing but figured I would come here and ask anyway.